# in react can't get new value after immediately setState

Tags: reactjs

I am working with Reactjs. in which I am setting error if not properly entered.
Sample code is:

```
handleChange: function() {
 if(shares) {
   this.setState({
     error_shares:''
   })
 } 
 if(this.state.error_shares === ''){
  console.log('entered!!')
 }
}
```

Here value of `error_state` doesn't reflect changed value in next if

Comment: `setState` is an async operation. You probably don't need to do this though, right?

Comment: yes it is.but doesn't work immediately,for this you need react linkstate mixin. but still not working

Comment: Sure.. I mean in the code you posted you could just check if `shares` is true to know if it's an empty string or not, so maybe you didn't post the actual code you were having a problem with.

Comment: You can also pass a callback as second argument of `setState` method. It will be called after state actually changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is the desired behavior.

The reason why the value has not been updated is because your component has not been re-rendered yet.

If you need such a feature, you should use the `componentDidUpdate` callback.

See the lifecycle methods [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate).

**EXPLANATION**:

Here is how React works:

1. Each component is a function of `external props` + `internal state`
2. If a change in either of the two is triggered, the component is queued to be re-rendered (it is asynchronous so that the client application is not blocked).
3. See the above link for exact sequence of operations but here is a little proof of concept.

   ```
   import React from 'react';

   class Example extends React.Component {

       constructor(props, context) {
           super(props, context);
           // initial state
           this.state = {
               clicked: false
           };
       }

       componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
           console.log(this.state.clicked);   // this will show "true"
       }

       render() {
           return (
               <button 
                   onClick={() => {
                       this.setState({clicked: true}); 
                   }}
               >
               </button>
           );
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: Can you give give me a little detail explanation? you gave me hope

Answer (score 4):

`setState` is asynchronous in nature.

> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

so you can do something like this.

```
handleChange: function () {
    if ( shares ) {
        this.setState( {
            error_shares: ''
        }, function () {
            if ( this.state.error_shares === '' ) {
                console.log( 'entered!!' )
            }
        } )
    }
}
```

source: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't get update value in console just after setState. This is because as soon as setState is called, view is re-rendered. Hence to get updated value, you can check it inside `render() .`

```
render(){
 if(this.state.error_shares === ''){
    //your code.
 }
}
```

Comment: actually I am calling api instead of `console` i want this sequence get executed anyhow

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Why do you want fire setState and than calling your api. After api response you will gain need to call setState. Handle it using events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: so what's the solution?