# Can't use state value as props for child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react js app, I can't seem to use the state value as props for the child component.

In the parent component, `constructor`, the app has a null state called `selectedWarehouseID`.

This state(`selectedWarehouseID`) should update with some information in the `componentWillMount()` method.

Now, in the `render` method of the parent component I am embedding another child component that has this state as a props.

```
<ItemChooser
  productsByWarehouse = { this.state.selectedWarehouseID }
/>
```

Now here's the problem, in the child component, the value of `this.props.productsByWarehouse` is always `null`. I found a nice [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36124127/981586) of why this happens, but how to wait for the data that updates in the parents `componentWillMount()` to access the updated value of the state that being passed in the child component props?

Comment: Instead of updating the state in `componentWillMount`, update it in `componentDidMount` and use setState, child will automatically get the updated state value as props. If that calculation is not big, then directly call a function from constructor and initialize the state by that value, instead of null.

Comment: @MayankShukla That didn't working, still the value is null

Comment: can you show the code how you are updating the state in that method? one ques "are you storing the props values in state of child component?"

Comment: Yes, i am storing the props in the state of child comp. in componentwillmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions are:

**1.** You are storing the `props` value in `state` of child component so, Update the state of child component whenever any change happen to `props` values (state of parent). For that use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method.

**[componentWillReceiveProps():](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**

> is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. If you need
>   to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset
>   it), you may compare this.props and nextProps and perform state
>   transitions using this.setState() in this method.

Like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
   this.setState({
      value: newProps.productsByWarehouse
   });
}
```

**Note:** Replace value by the actual key in which you are storing the value.

**2.** Don't store the `props` values in state of child component, directly use `this.props.productsByWarehouse`, Whenever you change the parent state values, child will automatically get the updated value in `props`.