# setState not updating the array in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am working on a react app where I have to change keys of objects in an array.Here's my code:

```
getInterfaces(){
    //assign a array to interfaceOption state
    let interfaceOptions=[
      {
        "interface_name": "ORU",
        "interface_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "interface_name": "MLM",
        "interface_id": "2"
      },
    ]
   
    //change interfaceOptions keys to title and value
    let interfaceOptionsWithTitle = interfaceOptions.map(function(item){
      return {
        title: item.interface_name,
        value: item.interface_id
      }
    })
    console.log(interfaceOptionsWithTitle)
    this.setState({
      interfaceOptions: interfaceOptionsWithTitle
    })
  
    //print updated interfaceOptions
    console.log(this.state.interfaceOptions)

  }
```

Here I initially assign a array,then I change its keys and print it using console.log and it prints the updated array but when I then setState the array and console log it again,it returns a empty array.Can someone help me to understand this?

Will this work if I want to update interfaceOptions?

```
this.state.interfaceOptions = this.state.interfaceOptions.map(item => {
      return {
        title: item.interface_name,
        value: item.interface_id
      };
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36124127/8269427)

Comment: setState is an async function, use the callback to print our put the console.log outside getInterfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becasue state only has new value when component re-render. So just put  `console.log` to outside function `getInterfaces` to see the new value

```
getInterfaces(){
...
}
console.log(this.state.interfaceOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous in nature, you are trying to update the value and printing it in next line which will always give you the old state value because at the time when the browser tries to print the value the state is not updated, it takes some time to update the value.

If you want to print the updated state value you have pass a callback function  to setState and print the value
e.g

```
    this.setState({
      interfaceOptions: interfaceOptionsWithTitle
    },() => {
     console.log(this.state.interfaceOptions)
    })
```

Note: The callback function in the above setState will be executed after the rendering is completed.

Comment: can you check the second part of the question too?

Comment: @rudeTool This is not the recommended way, it will update the value but will not trigger a re-render